# get all properties from data class that are not null in Kotlin

Tags: class, kotlin

I have a data class "Sample" and wanted to collect all the values that are not null, in this case the result should be "name and "type".
How to iterate over the data class members without reflection?

```
 data class Sample(
        var name: String = "abc",
        var model: String? = null,
        var color: String? = null,
        var type: String? = "xyz",
        var manufacturer: String? = null
    ) : Serializable
```

Comment: It can't be done without reflection.

Comment: if you don't want to use reflection, then try to serialize to `Map` using json serialization, and check each value

Comment: As @sidgate says, if you need to iterate over the values, a `Map` would seem like a better approach than object properties.  What else will you be doing with these values?

Comment: @sidgate To be precise: serializing to a `Map` does use reflection

Answer (score 2):

You can use `toString` method of data classes and parse its output

```
Sample(name=abc, model=null, color=null, type=xyz, manufacturer=null)
```

with following code:

```kotlin
val nonNulls = Sample().toString()
        .substringAfter('(')
        .substringBeforeLast(')')
        .split(", ")
        .map { with(it.split("=")) { this[0] to this[1] } }
        .filter { it.second != "null" }
        .map { it.first }

println(nonNulls)
```

Result:

```
[name, type]
```

The obvious restrictions:

1. Works only for `data` classes
2. Ignores properties that have string value "null"

Comment: Parsing the output of `toString()` is not a good idea.  It's fragile, easily broken if someone updates `toString()` in any way; it's likely to break if someone creates a subclass and overrides `toString()`; it's also inefficient.  (In fact, the rule ‘Always Override toString()’ in Joshua Bloch's [Effective Java](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-java/9780134686097/) specifically instructs to “provide programmatic access to the information contained in the value returned by toString”, so programmers don't need to do that.)

Comment: @gidds Though Kotlin is JVM language, Kotlin is NOT Java. 1) Data classes are final and can't be inherited from. 2) Overriding `toString` is reasonable for Java classes, but much less reasonable for Kotlin `data class`es as they already have decent built-in implementation provided by compiler.

Comment: True; Kotlin isn't Java.  But it shares a lot, and many of the same principles still apply.  This case is a `data class` which, as you say, is currently final (though that's long been a subject for discussion).  But you can still override `toString()` (e.g. to abbreviate long properties or hide unnecessary ones), and so parsing its output is still fragile.  And it's still inefficient.  Above all, it's a code smell — suggesting that the overall design may not be a good fit for the requirements.